# Transpose Pandas dataframe from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have checked [pandas.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), and various SO posts, but couldn't find a solution for this problem below.

I have this dataframe:

[image]

Could you please show me how to change it to this format? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Question:   Are the duplicate column names part of your problem, or can we rename those columns to have unique names?

Comment: Hi @ScottBoston, I assumed you referred to column `Var 2`? It can be changed to different name; I just made it the same for illustration purpose.

Comment: See my solution below, I rename he Second, Var1 and Var2 to Var1a and Var2a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1':[*'xyz'],
                  'Var2':['a']*3,
                  'Var1a':[1,5,9],
                  'Var2a':[2,6,10],
                  'Var3':[3,7,11],
                  'Var4':[4,8,12]})

df_out = df.set_index(['Var2', 'Var1']).stack().unstack(1).droplevel(1)
df_out = df_out.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
df_out
```

Output:

```
   x  y   z
a  1  5   9
a  2  6  10
a  3  7  11
a  4  8  12
```

Comment: Amazing! It's almost there. How can I remove the row/header Var2 to make the final dataframe contains only 1 header row (Var1, x, y, z). that is, Var1 column will contain values `a`?

Comment: @Nemo Those were just axis names.